# Looping audio delayed start - Crosswalk + Howler + Android

Tags: android, audio, crosswalk, howler.js

We have created an app and for some reason any sound played through Howler that is set to loop has a 30 second or so delay before it actually begins when played on an Android device. Its as if the entire sounds needs to be loaded prior to playing. The sound itself is stored locally on the device and we are using .ogg's. Also this hasn't been an issue before  and its only since we updated crosswalk to version 23+ (2.3.0)

Has anybody else come across this or potentially have a fix for this?

Comment: you should provide a minimum code example of your current approach to this problem to help others to reproduce it.

Comment: In my config file we have this:

 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.3.0">
        <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
    </plugin>

And we are using Howler version 2.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found out the issue was to do with Howler and not Crosswalk. Essentially when setting up a new Howl we need to pass the parameter html5:true.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let gasLooper;
let gasSound = new Howl({
    preload:true
  , src: require('./assets/audio/Gas-loop.mp3')
  , autoplay: true
  , volume: 0.5
  , onplay: ()=>{
    gasLooper = setTimeout(()=>{
      gasSound.play();
    },450);
  }
  , onstop: ()=>{
    clearTimeout(gasLooper);
  }
});
```